# Trigger to check if a column is updated and another one has a specific value

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

I'm writing a trigger for a SQL Server database. What I want is, when a table is updated, check if a specific column is updated or not and if another column has a value = `'W'` or not. If it is so, the date column should be updated in the old row and a new row should be inserted.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[member_in_test] (
[id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[chart_no]    INT          NULL,
[team_id]     INT          NOT NULL,
[position_id] INT          NULL,
[member_id]   INT          NOT NULL,
[FromD]       DATE         NOT NULL,
[ToD]         DATE         NULL,
[credence]    NVARCHAR (1) DEFAULT ('W') NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [member_in_pkt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC);)
```

And this is my `IF` statement: if `position_id` is updated and `credence` not equal to `'W'`, the `ToD` will be updated and a new row will be inserted into the table.

```
if update(position_id) && credence !='W'
begin
update member_in set ToD= GETDATE() 

insert into member_in(team_id,position_id,member_id,fromD,chart_no) values(@team_id,@Position_id,@Member_ID ,getdate(),@Chart_no);
end
```

So could anyone help me to create the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but here is a start.  It looks like you are trying to emulate a slowly changing dimension.  I used `DATETIME` for `FromD` and `ToD` so you could better see the data changing.

If I have misunderstood your requirements, please update your question with more information.

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists dbo.member_in_test;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[member_in_test] (
[id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[chart_no]    INT          NULL,
[team_id]     INT          NOT NULL,
[position_id] INT          NULL,
[member_id]   INT          NOT NULL,
[FromD]       DATETIME         NOT NULL,
[ToD]         DATETIME         NULL,
[credence]    NVARCHAR (1) DEFAULT ('W') NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [member_in_pkt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC));

insert into dbo.member_in_test(chart_no,team_id,position_id,member_id,FromD,ToD,credence) 
values(1,1,1,1,'2018-09-03',null,'A');
go

--Trigger definition
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[member_in_test_Modified] ON [dbo].[member_in_test]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Update the rows that were changed to have current date in ToD
    --We're only interested in rows where the position_id changed and
    --the original row had credence <> 'W'
    UPDATE m
    SET ToD = getdate()
    FROM dbo.member_in_test m
    JOIN deleted d ON d.id = m.id
    JOIN inserted i ON i.id = d.id
        AND i.position_id <> d.position_id
        AND d.credence <> 'W'

    --Insert into table all rows from inserted, but make ToD = null
    INSERT INTO dbo.member_in_test (
        chart_no
        ,team_id
        ,position_id
        ,member_id
        ,FromD
        ,ToD
        ,credence
        )
    SELECT chart_no
        ,team_id
        ,position_id
        ,member_id
        ,getdate()
        ,NULL
        ,credence
    FROM inserted
END;
GO

-----------------------------------------------------------------
--Verification
--select data before and after update to verify trigger execution
select * from dbo.member_in_test;
go
update dbo.member_in_test set position_id = 2;
go
select * from dbo.member_in_test;
```

**Date before update**

```
| id | chart_no | team_id | position_id | member_id | FromD                   | ToD  | credence |
|----|----------|---------|-------------|-----------|-------------------------|------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | 1       | 1           | 1         | 2018-09-03 00:00:00.000 | NULL | A        |
```

**Data after update**

```
| id | chart_no | team_id | position_id | member_id | FromD                   | ToD                     | credence |
|----|----------|---------|-------------|-----------|-------------------------|-------------------------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | 1       | 2           | 1         | 2018-09-03 00:00:00.000 | 2018-09-03 06:15:33.740 | A        |
| 2  | 1        | 1       | 2           | 1         | 2018-09-03 06:15:33.740 | NULL                    | A        |
```